# paypal express checkout set paypal fee additional

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, express-checkout

I have integrate paypal express checkout in our website. as i know and get information from paypal documentation.

Need to set Amount parameter in request input and paypal deduct fee based on amount, but i want paypal add fee additional on amount.

Example : 
**Product amount : $100.00;**

Paypal deduct fee 2.9% on $100.00 but i want add aditional 2.9% on main amount, like :

**Amount = 100.00

Fee = 2.9%**

Than Total amount is = **$100.00 + 2.9% = $102.90**

means i want paypal automatically set his fee on checkout page and charge to user.

Can anyone help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add that fee on to your order you'll need to do so prior to sending the user to PayPal, or you could also do it on your review page after the user is returned from PayPal.

Most people just add this to their cart as a "handling fee" or whatever you want to call it.  If you want to be more accurate you should use the 2.9% + .30 formula.

Comment: But if i ad 2.9% + 0.30 then paypal deduct fee on whole amount. just like 
If amount = 100
If i add 2.9% + 0.30 = 3.20

Total = 103.20

but now paypal deduct 2.9% on  203.30, this is not correct.

Comment: Right, you're not going to be able to make it exact for that very reason.  Some people like to add a little extra cushion on top of it to make up for the difference.  Personally, I think passing that fee on to the buyer just deters them from buying.  If you're really that worried about just raise the price of your product/service to cover it.  Psychologically, I think more people would spend $10 on an item with free shipping and no handling fee than would spend $8 on an item with a $2 handling fee.